# Change attribute of HTML elements of all tag?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there a way to change a particular attribute of all HTML elements of a certain tag with javascript or php (or anything else)? For example, I'd like to use javascript to change all "<a>" elements on the page to have the "target='_blank'" attribute. Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following jQuery code will add a target="_blank" attribute to all anchor (a) elements on a page:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

You will need to include a copy of jQuery in your HTML's head element, before the script above. So your head element will look something like:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Does the jquery code itself have to be in the head, or just the "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"?

Comment: @user1046024: If this is all you need the JavaScript for, don't load jQuery.

Comment: @user1046024: Neither have to be in the head, but the script element for jQuery (the first one) should come before the other. Though the common consensus seems to be to use Dennis' solution, he doesn't specify where the code should be placed for it to apply to all links properly.

Answer (score 6):

`getElementsByTagName` will grab all your anchors and then you can iterate over them:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a"), len = list.length;
while( len-- ) {
    list[len].target = "_blank";
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zwbCS/

Comment: +1 for not suggesting including jquery or similar for a task which can be accomplished just as easily without.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` can be replaced with `document.links`, which is slightly more efficient (`target` makes no sense at a non-link anchor)..

Comment: @RobW That would work for the specific example provided by the OP, but my answer was directed at the more general idea of changing "a particular attribute of all HTML elements of a certain tag".

Comment: -1 for avoiding jQuery or similar. If you're going to avoid it at the expense of a DOM-is-ready method, you should mention that the script won't work unless it is placed after all the elements it could affect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not seem to distinguish the difference between server-side languages (like PHP), and client-side (like Javascript). Read up on the difference [here](http://www.virtualshowrooms.co.za/articlepage.php?cp=101).

Answering your question, though. The best option (and the easiest IMHO) for you is to get [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and use the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using [jquery](http://www.jquery.com)  you should be able to do something like

```
$("a").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JQuery example, in case you want to want to open in new window only the external links:

```
var myHosts = [ // just in case you are using full abs paths
    'www.mydomain.com'
];

jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery( 'a[href^="http"]' ).each( function()
    {
        if ( jQuery.inArray( this.hostname, myHosts ) == -1 && this.href.indexOf( location.hostname ) == -1 )
            jQuery( this ).attr('target','_blank');
    });
});
```

IMHO forcing visitors to do it your way is not a good idea. Modern browsers have easy to use shortcut keys for opening of the links in new window/tab. So if the visitor found your site so incredibly useful, he will back to you, even if he leave your site by clicking on external link.

If you want to make a hint to your visitors about external links on your site, I suggest you to put an icon in the link(by CSS for example) and to modify and use the script from above to append desired CSS class to that links. Like:

```
jQuery(function()
{
    jQuery( 'a[href^="http"]' ).each( function()
    {
        if ( jQuery.inArray( this.hostname, myHosts ) == -1 && this.href.indexOf( location.hostname ) == -1 )
            jQuery( this ).addClass('external_link ');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.external_link { padding-right: 20px; background: url(path/to/the/image) no-repeat right top; }
```